# Django - Error with Attempted access

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-settings

in models.py, in the row:

```
file_pdf_fattura_proforma_solo_amministrazione = models.FileField (upload_to = "/home/alex/Desktop/project/media/proforma", max_length=20000, blank=True)
```

but When i Upload a pdf file:

Attempted access to '/home/alex/Desktop/project/media/proforma/contract_hosting.pdf' denied.

The directory project/media/proforma are with permissions 777.
I need to change settings?

Any Idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) directory should be *relative* to your `MEDIA_ROOT` settings so you should only need `(upload_to = "proforma, ..."`

Comment: But, so I add that dir in MEDIA_ROOT, but i must add a row in urls.py? for ex: url(r'^/home/alex/Desktop/project/media/proforma/',  "home.views.index") ? or else?